# How long is the request queue on a Vista-system?

Tags: java, networking, operating-system

I'm currently hacking on a new project, a web-app. But something's wrong, and I think it's Vistas fault, when I'm stress-testing the app, not all of the requests are answered.

The only thing I can think of is that the queue of incomming requests is getting too long, I've googled around, but can't find out how long the queue is, only that it depends on OS. Tough this may simply be because I don't know the "real" name for it;)

The project is written in Java SE.

If someone knows the answer I'd be really happy as I can't find it myself anywhere;)

UPDATE: The app is just a pet-project, and I won't be running it on a Vista machine when it's done. I've even been thinking of running it on a Solaris box, just to try Solaris:)

There are no errors or anything, but the request counter is way too low. Testing is done from Opera, with 30 tabs on auto-refresh every one second. I know, it's not the right way to do it, but it works:)

I don't use any frameworks, EE or anything, just pure Java SE.

Comment: Need more info, such as what type of server container you are running against...

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing a server app, but running it on Vista, you may be hitting the hard limit for inbound network connections on the Vista OS.  I've seen numbers from 5 (for Home Basic) up to 25 (for Business Pro and Ultimate) simultaneous connections allowed.

Vista is not designed as a Server OS.  If you want more simultaneous network connections, and you want to run Windows, get a license for one of the Windows Server products.  Alternately, you can run on some *NIX system.